# iOS HTTP Request called twice

Tags: ios, httprequest, nsurlrequest, http-get

I have a function which makes GET request to the server. It works fine but for some reason it's called twice. I call function when a button is pressed.

This is function code:

```
-(void) GETasync: (NSString *) path{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                              [NSURL URLWithString: path]
                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSHTTPURLResponse * response;
    NSError * error;
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];  
    NSLog(@"data received");
}
```

So I see in output:

```
2012-03-07 16:36:41.509 KW2[24136:bf03] data received
2012-03-07 16:36:41.694 KW2[24136:bf03] data received
```

I also have a function for POST request and it's the same trouble with it.

Comment: Can you please show the code where you make the call to this method?

Comment: How have you hooked up the button to that method?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the connection POST. You button event is being called morethan once. How are you assinging the events on your button?

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue. I haven't figured out why, but I do think it will end up being related to something else calling your method (and mine) twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just in that I wired IBOutlets from `File'Owner` and `First Responder` to buttons in IB.

After removing wires from `File's Owner`, the method started to be called only one time.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are printing out that log within your delegate method `connection:didReceiveData:`. That method can be called multiple times for one single connection - in fact it is commonly called at least twice.

From the documentation:

The delegate is periodically sent connection:didReceiveData: messages as the data is received. The delegate implementation is responsible for storing the newly received data.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

EDIT: I see that in your latest edits you have added that logging information (or maybe I did not see it right away - shame on me).

Are you possibly calling that method by a notification handler? If so, have you possibly double-registered for that notification -> hence your handler is invoked twice.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to check the IBAction connections for your button in Interface Builder. If you copy and paste buttons in IB, you can end up having 2 or more identical IBAction connections for a button, which would cause the method to be executed twice with just one button click.